# C# - Insert new data to database using EF6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

so i have this code on my function (activated by a button click):

```
entry ent = new entry { prodId = query1 , prodQty = int.Parse(textBox.Text) , hospId = query4 , contId = query5 , freqMaintenance = int.Parse(textBox1.Text), empId = this.emp });

ctx.entries.InsertOnSubmit(ent);

ctx.ent.SubmitChanges();
```

and the table structure from the database is like this (brief).
.

> entryId int identity(1,1) primary key [not null],
>
> prodId int foreign key [not null],
>
> prodQty int [null],
>
> hospId int foreign key [null],
>
> contID int foreign key [not null],
>
> freqMaintenance int [not null],
>
> dateRec date [not null] default sysdate,
>
> empId int foreign key [not null] ,
>
> approved bit [null],

im using SQL server Compact 4.0 EF6.0+ Visual Studio.

What i want to do is insert a data into the table. i tried using `.SaveChanges` and `.SubmitChanges` but there is a error in the syntax.

Comment: What is `ent` in your `ctx` object?

Comment: ent is a object i created.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) you can insert new entity like this:

```
entry ent = new entry { prodId = query1 , prodQty = int.Parse(textBox.Text) , hospId = query4 , contId = query5 , freqMaintenance = int.Parse(textBox1.Text), empId = this.emp });
ctx.entries.Add(ent);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Also according to same article you can add new entity to context by explicitly assigning that state is "Added":

```
entry ent = new entry { prodId = query1 , prodQty = int.Parse(textBox.Text) , hospId = query4 , contId = query5 , freqMaintenance = int.Parse(textBox1.Text), empId = this.emp });
ctx.Entry(ent).State = EntityState.Added; 
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I am not sure how you implemented your context but error in syntax is maybe because of `ent`:

ctx.**ent**.SubmitChanges();

Comment: it throwing me this exception : `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' in EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: @JulioMotol In that case I think that your problem maybe is not in context! It looks like that you have problem with some duplicate id somehow. I see that you use `identity(1,1) ` but can you please verify for me does everything looks OK with IDs? Did you update yuor entity framework?

Comment: @JulioMotol Maybe this article can help you to solve error message: http://www.technologycrowds.com/2015/07/system-data-entity-infrastructure-DbUpdateException.html

Answer (score 0):

May be the following code wil works for you.

```
ctx.Set<Entry>().Add(ent);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```